# Solving the integral $\int \frac{2dx}{(x-2)(x-1)x}$

Tags: integers

$\int \frac{2dx}{(x-2)(x-1)x}$

Any help with how to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: What method do you think will apply? You must have worked with this type of expression before. How do you "simplify" such an expression for the purpose of integrating it?

Comment: Converting the expression into a sum! Pretty easy, it just didn't click before.

Comment: Typically, you will get more help and more upvotes if you indicate what you've tried, and show where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fraction expansion

$$\frac{2}{(x-2)(x-1)x}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2}$$

The rest is easy.

Comment: Thankyou! It will take some time for the right approach to click right away i guess.